# EA Addin - EA_OnPreDeleteConnector is not triggered when used with Relationship Matrix

Tags: add-in, enterprise-architect

I created an addin in C#. When I create a connector from Relationship Matrix then  API **EA_OnPreNewConnector(Repository repository, EventProperties info)** is triggered, but when I delete this connector from the Relationship Matrix (right click -> "Delete Relashioship")  the API **EA_OnPreDeleteConnector(Repository repository, EventProperties info)** is not triggered. Why? Is there another API to use in this context?

Note: I'm using this API **EA_OnPreDeleteConnector(Repository repository, EventProperties info)** when I delete manually the connector using "Delete" button from the keyboard and the API is triggered. That means the API is written properly in C# code.
Also this API is triggered if I go in the diagram where the connector is displayed and right click -> "Delete Connector".

Comment: Well, the FM says _delete a connector on a diagram_ and not _in a matrix_. Needless to say that a fearture request is futile. Seem to remember having read a post about that on the forum not too long ago.

Comment: Uhm, time goes by fast: https://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,4172.msg119286.html#msg119286

Comment: 2012 :) still don't know how to catch the event... or what workaround to try

Comment: Well, simply abandon any hope :-/ Maybe the "fix" was the FM. Gotcha.

Comment: The "proper" channel is to report a bug to Sparx: https://sparxsystems.com/support/forms/bug_report.html